# How to request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions in a fragment

Tags: java, android

I've seen lots of questions about this but I still can't solve my problem.
I have a fragment called `CameraFragment.java` which opens a camera and saves the taken picture. The problem is, to save that I need to have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions... I've added these lines to my Manifest.xml:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

But in my **logcat**, when I run this code to save the image:

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap, String image_name) {

    final String appDirectoryName = "Feel";
    String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File myDir = new File(root);
    myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname = "Image" + image_name + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    //if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    Log.i("LOAD", root + fname);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I still get this error: 
`W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Imageimagem1.jpg (Permission denied)`

I am not sure but I think that this error comes from no permissions to write the file... How can I give this permissions in runtime?

Comment: Do you ask this permission at some point in your app, before this snippet is called ?

Comment: Well, the only thing I have related to permissions are those xml lines

Comment: If you are using android 6.0 (Marshmallow) you must ask run time permission else you can go to your app and enable storage manually.

Comment: run time permissions! please look into this https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

Comment: You will have to ask for permission in run time according to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Click here](http://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) for run time permissions! please look into this github.com/Karumi/Dexter

Comment: This might be a noob question but, when I write `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` part becomes red. Do I need to declare it? If yes, than with what value?

Comment: in class you should use multi permissions at same time feature which is provided in dexter library

Comment: I'm using multiple permissions. I just can't set which ones because the permission just says `Cannot resolve symbol WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: Found the problem. I should be using `android.Manifest.permissions`

Comment: yes, you need to add android. thank you for using dexter.

Comment: No problem. Dexter is nice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a class, with a method asking for storage permission

```
public class PermissionManager {
public static boolean checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(final Context context) {
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    (Activity) context,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                showDialog("External storage", context,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            } else {
                ActivityCompat
                        .requestPermissions(
                                (Activity) context,
                                new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                                101);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Used in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 101:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission given",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //saveImage(finalBitmap, image_name); <- or whatever you want to do after permission was given . For instance, open gallery or something 
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,
                    grantResults);
    }
}
```

In your case, you'll also check for it before saving the file

```
if (PermissionManager.checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(this)){
        saveImage(finalBitmap, image_name);
    }
```

Comment: `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is red. Do I need to declare it? If yes with what value?

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:node="replace"/>` in your manifest file and import the class in that `PermissionManager` class;

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PermissionDispatcher](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Managing-Runtime-Permissions-with-PermissionsDispatcher) to handle it very gently AFAIK it works in all versions.

Hope this will help you